# Alternative to REST when passing objects between servers

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, ejb, jndi, rmi

I have a spring-mvc project as a frontend project. My datasources are accessed by a second javaee project. This backend grands access to all data my frontend requires, by providing **REST services**. The REST-Service provides objects, by returning **XML**. This XML will then get **marshaled** by my frontend.

So when my frontend project requires current data, I create an `HttpUrlConnection`, then I call the REST-Service of my backend.

E.g. I want to get a collection of all movie objects:

```
URL url = new URL(URLSAFE.REST_ALL_MOVIES);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                connection.getResponseCode();

                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                Source sauce = new StreamSource(is);
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Movies.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

                JAXBElement<Movies> e = unmarshaller.unmarshal(sauce, Movies.class);
                Movies m = e.getValue();
                this.MOVIELIST = m;
                connection.disconnect();
```

After I added some remote ejb lookups for logging services, I came up with the idea to use rmi for passing objects. However I learned I cant cast the object to my frontend and that there is a big difference between a local object and a object you access by rmi.

But what would be a good attempt for passing objects between servers? I need to pass objects to the frontend because I got to use them with **JSP**.

Comment: You are in java environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client.htm#BABEIGIH You need not do what you are doing for a rest-application

Comment: Your starting assumption that you MUST pass objects is wrong. Passing objects across the network is a terrible idea, as anyone who had the misfortune to do DCOM or CORBA can tell you.

Comment: But is it a terrible idea to put a backend between the spring-mvc frontend and the datasources?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at this [Spring.io guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/). Usage of RestTemplate can remove a lot of boilerplate you have in example, and map REST resources onto POJOs. XML shouldn't be any barrier, because Spring should significantly help you abstract it.